# How to type a grave accent (aka ` backtick &#96; ) in markdown?

Tags: markdown

If you type `hello amazing world` and want to have a single ` to either side of amazing, how do you do it?  I've tried escaping the ` with a back slash and using escaped html like `&#96;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [Code section](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) of the Markdown syntax page:

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:
>
> ```
> ``There is a literal backtick (`) here.``
> ```

For example,

```
``hello `amazing` world``
```

renders as

`` hello `amazing` world ``

**Edit:** Re-reading this, I wonder if you want to use single backticks *outside of* code blocks. You [should be able to backslash-escape them](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash):

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax…
>
> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

This works on Stack Overflow, e.g.

```
hello \`amazing\` world
```

renders as

hello `amazing` world

If this doesn't work you'll have to provide more information about the Markdown processor you're using.

Comment: Is for a comment on GitHub.  The double backtick at the start and finish to allow literal backticks within (the first example you show) works like a charm.  I had tried three backticks which I thought hadn't worked but now I try it again it also works so I guess I had just made a mistake somewhere.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the GitHub and StackOverflow processors seem to have some trouble when the last character _before_ the double backtick is _also_ a backtick. The only workaround I found was putting some extra space before the last double backtick. ``Here it definitely `works` `` (with a space before the last double backtick), but `this alternative also \`works\`` (using single backticks and a backslash before each backtick inside the code section).

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn, on SO, in _comments_ backticks are a better solution: `\`\\`\``. This avoids the extra space shown in your comment. In _posts_ this doesn't work and spaces with varying numbers of backticks are required: `\`\` \` \`\``.

Comment: @Chris — oh, standards! The good thing about them is how many there are to choose from ;-)

Comment: how to input `` ` `` without space ?  `\`` seems not work

Comment: @yurenchen, I'm not totally clear on what you're asking. You want to mark a single backtick in inline code markers? In any case, it might depend on the implementation. Even here, on Stack Overflow, backticks work differently in posts and comments.

Comment: @Chris thanks.  yes, depend on implementation. detail in downstairs answer.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:**
 this is a test answer to show different markdown behavior in stackoverflow answer & comment.
 please don't Delete me.

follow lines are markdown test code, they also post as comment below:

### raw code

```
test msg: how to input  `` ` `` without space ?  `\`` seems not work
```

### result

test msg: how to input  `` ` `` without space ?  ``` seems not work

---

### conclusion

seems not same between in `comment` and `answer`, 
in `preview` and `result`.

Comment: test msg: how to input  `` ` `` without space ?  `\`` seems not work

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case - to use markdown blocks inside markdown, and the code blocks within, which is usually wrapped with **3** grave accents, wrap the outer (markdown block) with **4** grave accents, literally you'll get the following:

`````
````markdown
# H1
```javascript
let foo = `Hello, ${name}, world`;
```
````
`````

To print the block above, I've wrapped it with 5 graven accents and it will be rendered as `markdown` code block:

[image]